# Birthday paradox- valid from 23 people and why not for 22 people ?

Tags: probability, number-theory

My question is why birthday paradox is applicable for 23 people's group and why not for 22 people group.

Request you to please guide on this .. I will be greatful to you.

Thanks..

Comment: Because the probability of two people in a group having the same birthday is greater than $1/2$ for $23$ people, but not for $22$.

Comment: I don't understand why the down-votes here. I'm assuming sultan knows **that** it applies for 23, and not 22 people...but may not understand how the probability is computed...Perhaps [this will help.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Understanding_the_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Following on Alex Becker's remark, the probability of a match with $22$ people is less than $\frac 12$, which people don't find surprising.  In this case there is a linkage between "paradox" and "surprising".  What people find surprising is that $23$ suffice to raise the probability above $\frac 12$.  I would suggest that important thing for the "paradox" is that the number is so far below $182 \approx \frac {365}2$, not whether it is $22$ or $23$.